# Ошибка при коммите, метод Put, subversion (svn)

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Выдает при коммите такую ошибку:

> The HTTP method 'PUT' is not allowed on

http://prntscr.com/hj4aii,
 гуглил много, возможно гуглил не там и не то =)
 прошу помощи опытных свнщиков )

Comment: А в коммандной строке не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, наверное, уже протух и нет логов с сервера чтобы исследовать проблему дальше. Но я бы на вашем месте проверил, что ваш сервер собран с up-to-date версией Subversion. Проверьте ещё и версию клиента.

Вижу по скриншоту, что вы коммитите *.js файл. Антивирус на вашем компе или на стороне сервера вполне может не давать вам заккомитить изменения в *.js файл. Проверяйте настройки антивируса.